# Is it possible to setup PC as a server over LAN, and run a real (test) website on it?

Tags: webserver, lamp

Here's what I have - - a Intel dual-core PC with 6GB RAM and 320GB SATA HDD (I have a new model Sony VAIO laptop too, if that's any better); and a 8mbps home LAN (Broadband) connection. I do not know if port 80 is open (is there a way to check that out?).

Now what I want to be able to do is... turn this PC into a working LAMP (L=CentOS) webserver setup, then install wordpress and run a real website at a real domain (which would be http://comicb.us). Is this possible? If so, is there a guide available on the internet? (I couldn't find any.) or can anyone guide me?

I am a beginner, so if it looks silly, please take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: I should point out this may be violating your ISP's terms of service.

Comment: @Ben Pilbrow I will only be testing it. The website won't be live for long.

Comment: @Aahan - so you'll only *sorta* be violating the TOS, then?

Comment: @ErikA lol, either way, _YES!_ (But I think I can get away with it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The port question is up to you. Check your router, forward your port. That's it.
The IP/Domain. Two options:

- IF you have a dynamic IP, you will need a [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/) like service. (DynDNS got a client application which you run from cron / keep it running in the background. It'll automatically update the domain entry, so it'll always point to your PC, even when you get a new IP.)
- IF you have or can get a static IP, you can simply point the domain
  later (when you have that static IP) to your PC.

Comment: +1 for DynDNS for dynamic IPs. My router even has an update client built in, so if I ever loose connection and get a new IP it updates my DynDNS automatically

Answer (score 0):

This takes many steps, but the first is to make sure you are allowed to host services on your ISPs connection. You also need to make sure you have a static IP with our ISP, this may cost additional cash on top of your monthly fee. At this time you should also ask them to make sure port 80 is open through their modem/router at your home. It will be your responsibility to make sure it is open in your own router and pointed at your computer.
You will then need to install LAMP and setup your website. At this point you can test it by just typing in the IP address (you may need to have NAT reflection enabled in your router for you to be able to view it publicly from inside your LAN).

Once you know that it is viewable from the outside, it is worth getting the domain setup. You will need to find a registrar and register your domain (you will want one that also offers basic DNS services as you will be acting as the host, unless you want to configure your own DNS too). You can then go to the config page for your domain and point to the correct name servers (yours or theirs) and then configure your A record to point the domain to your static IP. Once the DNS push goes through (4-48 hours depending on all legs involved) then your site is up and running with your domain name.